# Typescript method is return undefined with method decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript1.8

I apologize if it is a silly question. I am new with typescript and learning typescript decorators. I found a code: MethodDecorator to log the arguments and the result.

log decorator

```
function log (target: Object, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args:any[]) {
        //before
        console.log(`${key} method called with args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);

        let result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);

        //after
        console.log(`${key} method return value: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    }
    return descriptor;
}
```

I am using @log with setId and getId methods in Book class

book.ts

```
class Book{
    constructor(public id: number, public title: string, public publisher: string){}

    @log
    setId(id: number){
        this.id = id;
    }
    @log
    getId(): number{
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

> All code works fine but getId returns undefined when i run this code.

```
let book = new Book(1, "Learn TypeScript", "O\'Reilly Media");

let favBookId = book.getId();
console.log("Book before setId: ");
console.log(book);
console.log("Favourite book id: "+favBookId);

book.setId(5);
console.log("Book after setId: ");
console.log(book);
console.log("Favourite book id: "+favBookId);
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "removeComments": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

To compile and run:

```
tsc -p ./
node book.js
```

Output:

```
getId method called with args: []
getId method return value: 1
Book before setId:
Book {id: 1, title: 'Learn TypeScript', publisher: 'O\'Reilly Media' }
Favourite book id: undefined
setId method called with args: [5]
setId method return value: undefined
Book after setId:
Book {id: 5, title: 'Learn TypeScript', publisher: 'O\'Reilly Media' }
Favourite book id: undefined
```

I am not able to understand why setId is working as I want and getId is not??

```
tsc -v: Version 1.8.10
```

Comment: I have exaclty the same issue. Have you been able to find answers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why all the posts on the internet reference such examples, but I had problems of my own with the method decorator context regarding `originalMethod.apply(this, args);`

This indeed does NOT work AT ALL (I don't know if its a `ts` bug or something though).

After trial an error, I found that the following solution worked, allowing you to have the correct context inside your base class:

```
function myDecorator(target: Object, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {

        descriptor.value = function (...args:any[]) {
            // whatever code suits you here...
            // dont use "this", use "target"
            let result = originalMethod.apply(target, args);

        }
        return descriptor;
}
```

Now this allows you to do:

```
export class Yeah {
    @myDecorator()
    helloWord() {
        let n = 5;
        return this.multiply(n);
    }

    multiply(a: number) {
       return a * 2;
    }

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Passing the target as argument will provide the class Prototype instead of the actual instance. Using `this` is probably what most people want, but be sure to use an actual function instead of an arrow function.

Answer (score 4):

OMG, I thought your problem is the same with me but it's not.

The problem is just caused by that `you return nothing` when re-define the function.

#### Here is your original code block:

```js
descriptor.value = function (...args:any[]) {
        //before
        console.log(`${key} method called with args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);

        let result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);

        //after
        console.log(`${key} method return value: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    }
```

#### Now, return it and it will work correctly.

```js
descriptor.value = function (...args:any[]) {
        //...
        let result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        //...
        return result; //ADD HERE!!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a full working example:

```
function log(msg: string): MethodDecorator {
  return (
    target: Object,
    key: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      //before
      if (args.length >0)  console.log(`${msg} ${key.toString()} method called with args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
      let result = originalMethod!.apply(this, args);
      //after
      if (result) console.log(`${key.toString()} method return value: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}

class Book {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
    public publisher: string
  ) {}

  @log('setting ')
  setId(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  @log('getting ')
  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}

const a = new Book(1, "title", "publisher");
a.setId(2);
a.getId();
```

You can run it at [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=1#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-cIfsJhBBkDwcDhEAAhOBwIxpMRa0ggaDcWRuHwgDTIGAQJUsQhgECOcKueRFktlhRok4WN1oetiRul8s90WMcLt03xITRuQAAVQmAA5DgGLBrDPKHJ51AAJIsDAwSuIau1kgLdIio47ko7iOT6cYGcqKCLtCIZdyO+bjDUPc19YkTPyIPSBRGFFKoLzkaNx2zCUSjAOhkRTNMjAwABGcUACJYCgE5ULQ-scEHEhUN9HhCQYN8ACYiKqV8t19YQgA)